# HTTP 403 forbidden on web app deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications

after deploying my web app to a new server using the add web setup method, I tried to run it from the browser but I am getting the error http 403 forbidden. I tried using previous suggestions to similar questions by checking enable anonymous access, and using https and trying to access a page but did not work.The application runs fine on my machine when running it from visual studio, but fails after running the setup.exe file on the production server.
Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like IIS account dos not have permissions to access we root directory, so please verify that account which is running application pool for your website has access to your project home dir.

Additionally check web.config and our Windows authentication disabled.